# How to add attribute on element level in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to genearte this kind of xml using xsd

```
<UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers>
    <UserName errorCode= "1" errorMessage="">?</UserName>
    <UserName errorCode= "1" errorMessage="">?</UserName>
    ....
    ....
</UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers>
```

I tried this first

```
<xsd:element name="UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers" type="UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers"/>
<xsd:complexType name="UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers">  
    <xsd:sequence>  
        <xsd:element name="UnassignedUsers" type="UnassignedUsers" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="UnassignedUsers" type="UnassignedUsers"/>  
<xsd:complexType name="UnassignedUsers">  
    <xsd:sequence>  
        <xsd:element name="UserName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence> 
    <xsd:attribute name="errorCode" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="errorMessage" type="xsd:string" /> 
</xsd:complexType>
```

but this will generate something like this

```
<UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers>  
    <UnassignedUsers errorCode="" errorMessage="" >
        <UserName></UserName>
    </UnassignedUsers>  
    <UnassignedUsers errorCode="" errorMessage="" >
        <UserName></UserName>
    </UnassignedUsers>
...
....
</UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers>
```

If i use

```
<xsd:element name="UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers" type="UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers">  
    <xsd:sequence>  
        <xsd:element name="UserName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence> 
    <xsd:attribute name="errorCode" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="errorMessage" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

then this will generate

```
<UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers errorCode="" errorMessage="">  
<UserName></UserName>
</UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers>
```

How can i generate this using xsd

```
<UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers>
    <UserName errorCode= "1" errorMessage="">?</UserName>
    <UserName errorCode= "1" errorMessage="">?</UserName>
    ....
    ....
</UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers>
```

Thanks

Comment: that means do u want with xml errocode value as"1" and that ?(question mark) by default ?

Comment: @Naren no no not with value, no need for 1 and ?

Comment: Check below answer ..is it not correct ??

Comment: there are some online sites available  for this task xml-->xsd check this one http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the `UserName` element `type="xsd:string"` then it can't have attributes.  To allow *both* the text content *and* the attributes you need to give the element a `complexType` with `simpleContent` that *extends* `xsd:string`, and declare the attributes on that type rather than on the `UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers` type:

```
<xsd:element name="UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers" type="UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers"/>

<xsd:complexType name="UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers">
  <xsd:sequence>  
    <xsd:element name="UserName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:simpleContent>
          <xsd:extension base="xs:string">
            <xsd:attribute name="errorCode" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:attribute name="errorMessage" type="xsd:string" />
          </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType>
```

If you want to be able to declare other elements with the same attributes then you could use a named `complexType` instead of nesting it inside the `UserName` element:

```
<xsd:complexType name="valueWithError">
  <xsd:simpleContent>
    <xsd:extension base="xs:string">
      <xsd:attribute name="errorCode" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:attribute name="errorMessage" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="UnassignedSecurityRoleUsers">
  <xsd:sequence>  
    <xsd:element name="UserName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                 type="valueWithError"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can i define `<xsd:simpleContent>` separately so i can use it on other types two, because i need to define another element `InvalidOrganizationaGrioups` that is exactly same. Means require both text content and attribute.

Comment: @Basit not the `simpleContent` but rather its parent `complexType` - I've edited the answer with an example.